# Firebase Cloud Function - Reference.update failed

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting the following error when invoking a GCF:

**Error: Reference.update failed: First argument path specified exceeds the maximum depth that can be written (32) or object contains a cycle in property**

Done a bit of digging online but can't find the same issue. Without adding way too much info, I'm trying to add dish objects into a category object in Realtime Database. The odd thing is, the function works fine for the first 6 dishes, and when I try to add a 7th, this error pops up and the update method fails.

The full error log, with my unique property data is:

```
Error: Reference.update failed: First argument path specified exceeds the maximum depth that can be written (32) or object contains a cycle in property 

'users.sIRf7m1uWfa9j0iF6UuuzvdD5TG2.dishcategories.default01.dishes.u3o1p278vriqo3odeslle.categories.0.dishes.irdrl2q7blsi1y7ih3jhh.categories.0.dishes.v8pl7r9llhfp7sqmz7uikk.categories.0.dishes.2ee3ajy6d5vymneewgflze.categories.0.dishes.btdib119nz5cnm6zk5uu4t.categories.0.dishes.4wyu5yqyn2z0bgvcejix9.categories.0.dishes.w1cfcpktym7nkp76p521n.categories.0.createdDate'

    at ValidationPath.checkValid_ (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1035:19)
    at ValidationPath.push (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1015:14)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1478:18
    at Object.forEach (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:837:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1462:14)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1479:13
    at Object.forEach (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:837:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1462:14)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1479:13
    at Object.forEach (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:837:13)
```

Here's the cloud function code from index.ts:

```
// Now we need to check if this dish's categories already exist as user categories.
// If they do, we can add this newly created dish into them.
// If they don't, we can create them with this newly added dish in them.

dish.categories.forEach( async (dishCategory) => {
    const index = objectInArrayByID(dishCategory, userCategories)

    if ( index !== -1 ) {

        return userCategoriesRef.child(`${dishCategory.id}/dishes/${id}`).update(dish) // *** This is the update method producing the error in this case ***
    }

    else {

        await userCategoriesRef.child(`${dishCategory.id}`).update(dishCategory)

        return userCategoriesRef.child(`${dishCategory.id}/dishes/${id}`).update(dish)
    }

 })
```

Anyone know what this error means, and perhaps what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit: you're trying to write data that is more than `32` levels deep, or which contains a cyclic object.

Given the code you shared, the latter seems most likely: you're looping over each category of a dish, and then write that dish to each category again. The simplest fix I can think of is to write the dish-without-categories to each category:

```
dish_without_categories = dish;
delete dish_without_categories.categories;
dish.categories.forEach( async (dishCategory) => {
    const index = objectInArrayByID(dishCategory, userCategories)

    if ( index !== -1 ) {

        return userCategoriesRef.child(`${dishCategory.id}/dishes/${id}`).update(dish_without_categories)
    }
    else {

        await userCategoriesRef.child(`${dishCategory.id}`).update(dishCategory)

        return userCategoriesRef.child(`${dishCategory.id}/dishes/${id}`).update(dish_without_categories)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Frank - you hit the problem right on the head :)